# Make my custom module the home page

Tags: magento2

I want our `example.net' route to point to a custom module we have created.

This custom module is located at `app/code/Vendor/Module` and the page we want to serve is `/Controller/Index/Index.php`

So, if you currently navigate to `example.net/module` you will see the page, but we want to put this page at just `example.net`

Is this possible in Magento?

**Edit: If you don't need CMS, you can just change the 'default web URL' through the dashboard: see the accepted answer**

What I've tried so far is registering the module as a CMS page using the `UpgradeDataInterface` class, but I am confused as to what values should go into this function:

```
private function createCmsPage()
{
    /** @var PageInterface $cmsPage */
    $cmsPage = $this->pageInterfaceFactory->create();
    $cmsPage->setIdentifier('page-identifier')
        ->setTitle('Page Title')
        ->setContentHeading('Content Heading')
        ->setContent('Page HTML content')
        ->setPageLayout('1column')
        ->setData('stores', [0]);

    $this->pageRepository->save($cmsPage);
}
```

For things like `setTitle` and `setContent`, should I be linking these up to already existing values, say in my layout files? Really stuck on this and not able to find any good documentation or conversation on the issue; it might be too much of an edge case?

I tried running the script once, with titles, identifiers that I just arbitrarily decided. The page appears in `Content -> Pages`, and I'm able to set the homepage at `Stores -> Configuration`. But when I navigate to the page I just see blank content. Feels like I am not hooking something up right.

I just want this page (that we've already built using typical module creation, with layouts, templates, controllers, blocks, etc.) to exist at the root of our site. Impossible?

Comment: How do you setup the page in `Store -> Configuration` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your custom module route as **Default Web URL** in `Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Page > Default Web URL` (In case you don't want to create a new static page).

[image]

And then

[image]

Comment: Really nice and simple way.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already create a Page. Go to `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Page -> CMS Home Page`.

But don't forget to setup this page in `All Store View` as Main Website or your other site.

[image]

Hope It will help!

Comment: The problem is, the page that I have added to the CMS through UpgradeDataInterface doesn't have any of the content. Is there maybe a cache I should clear?

Comment: Try to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I appreciate the help; but how would Magento even know which page I am trying to upload? My module creates the page through various files such as a layout.xml, controller methods like Index.php and Post.php, it renders a template file through a block etc. 

What I want to ask is, is it even possible to set a page like this as the home page of the entire site? Am I able to upload an entire module to CMS this way?